# Background color of SafeArea with Custom AppBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar

I am having a custom App Bar in one of the widget with custom height. Here is how the implementation looks like

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100),
          child: UserSwitcherAppBar(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UserSwitcherAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Container(
          color: Colors.orange,
          child: [My User Image, Greeting Text and User name]
    }
}
```

Giving color to my `UserSwitcherAppBar` doesn't apply to `SafeArea` background color. This is shown as:

[image: Home with CustomAppBar]

But when we use default AppBar, example

```
class Profile extends StatelessWidget {
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
            title: const Text('Profile'),
            actions: [IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.logout))],
          ),
       );
    }
}
```

This is shown as: [image]

How can I show my custom app bar the same as the default app bar with an orange color background in SafeArea as well?

Comment: Wrap your `SafeArea` in a `Container` and give you color (orange) to it.

Comment: @iDecode This works, but now I have to give color at 2 places. Both at `Home` widget and `UserSwitcherAppBar`. Can we have a better solution? How to achieve behaviour like default `AppBar`?

Comment: You're doing it wrong in the first place. When you warp your `Scaffold` in `SafeArea`, you'll get white status bar.

Comment: @iDecode Please suggest the correct hierarchy. P.S. Stil in the learning flutter mode.

Comment: There are many ways to do it. The textbook approach would be to use `class UserSwitcherAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget` and override `preferredSize` property to return `100` height. In the `build()` method, you can then use `Container(color: Colors.orange, child: ...)`

Comment: Thanks @iDecode, your suggestion helped. Final hierarchy that helped me achieve, `Home -> Scaffold -> UserSwitcherAppBar`. `UserSwitcherAppBar (implementing PreferredSizeWidget) -> Container (with color) -> SafeArea -> My Custom Content`

Answer (score 0):

That's StatusBar and you change it's colour with

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
  SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.orange,
  ),
);
```

Put this in the build method of your first screen.